# Efficient conditional triggering of decoder in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am implementing an encoder-(dual-)decoder model in tensorflow. The decoder is RNN-type. The input to the decoder is a feature map, the output of the previous time-step and the hidden state of the decoder from the previous time-step. I only only want to trigger the decoder(s) when the prediction from the previous time-step is one of a particular set of tokens.

I have tried using `tf.boolean_mask` on the prediction of the previous time-step to remove those examples that do not predict a trigger-token. Below is an example:

```
# initialize input
dec_input = tf.expand_dims([token2integer['<start>']] * target.shape[0], 1)
features = encoder(img_tensor)
hidden = decoder.reset_state(batch_size=target.shape[0])

# make first prediction
predictions, hidden, _ = decoder(dec_input, features, hidden)

# add to total loss
loss += loss_function(dec_input, predictions)

# construct input of next time-step (here with teacher forcing)
dec_input =tf.expand_dims(target[:, i], -1)

#compute mask to only trigger for certain predictions
mask_struc = compute_mask_struc(dec_input) 

# apply mask to input
features = tf.boolean_mask(features, mask_struc)                    
hidden = tf.boolean_mask(hidden, mask_struc)
target = tf.boolean_mask(target, mask_struc ) 
dec_input = tf.boolean_mask(dec_input, mask_struc ) 

# make next prediction and so on ...
```

I have implemented this into a training function. My implementation is working but it is slow. And when I run the function as a graph (with @tf.function) it gets 10x slower. If I remove the `boolen_mask` and run as a graph (with @tf.function) it is faster than without the @tf.function.

How can I speed up the execution (with or without the @tf.function)?

My ideas:

- fix whatever is making the graph execution slow: I don't know how.
- find alternative approach (without `boolean_mask`): I need inspiration
- give up and try with PyTorch which I am more familiar with: not guaranteed to be faster.